# Merging two or more records in SQL query result with same dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a SQL query which basically looks like this:

```
select t1.Date,t1.Earnings
from table1 as t1
```

So the query result is as following:

```
    5.5.2015 20.0 
    5.5.2015 16.0
    5.5.2015 24.0
    6.6.2015 15.0
    6.6.2015 15.0
```

My question is: is there any way to merge these 3 dates into one(as they are same basically) and merge these numerical values so that the result would look like this:

```
5.5.2015 70.0
6.6.2015 30.0
```

Only those records with same date should be merged.

Can someone help me out with this please? Thanks!

Comment: GROUP BY, SUM(t1.Earnings)

Comment: I just did that... for some reason the query returns the same result??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
SELECT t1.Date, SUM(T1.Earnings) 
FROM table1 as t1
GROUP BY Date
```

If, however, your dates are stored as `DATETIME` and the time portions do not match, you'll need to cast them to `DATE` in order to get the grouping correct:

```
SELECT CAST(t1.Date AS DATE) Date, SUM(t1.Earnings)
FROM table1 as t1
GROUP BY CAST(t1.Date AS DATE)
```